# How can I simulate poisson process?

Tags: mathematical-physics, poisson-process

how can I simulate a single realization of the Poisson counting process as described above. Such that the discrete-amplitude random process X(t) counts the number of packets arriving in the time interval [0,t). Take your simulation total time to be 10 hours, time sampling step size to be 1 sec.

Assume that the average number of packets arriving per minute in a certain cell equal 10

I tried to simulate the poisson but I can't understand how to simulate it and how to compute the interval times between the arrival of each two successive packets

Comment: Have you chosen a programming language you'll be using for your simulation? This is likely a better question for stackoverflow.

Comment: yes I simulate using matlab

Answer (score 0):

The chance of an event in $1$ second is $\frac 1{6}$ because you have $10$ events per minute.  Throw a random number with that probability for whether an event happens.  You have an error because you can't have two events in one second, but the chance is rather small.  I would have taken a shorter interval to reduce that, but $1$ second is specified in the problem.

Comment: so lamda will be equal 1/6 ?

Comment: how can i simulate it and put the right interval of time ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: am i just write the equation of poisson and write the intervals ?

Comment: Your interval is defined as $1$ second.  What you are simulating is having an event or not in each second, not the specific time each event happens.

Comment: so the time interval will not be like this t=0:1:10 ?

Comment: The length of an interval is $1$ second.  The time will range from $0$ seconds to $36000$ seconds as specified in the problem.  I believe your output is expected to be a list of times when an event happens, each time being measured to $1$ second.  The list should be about $1/6$ of the times, so about $6000$ times long.

Comment: lambda = 1/6;
nPeriods = 36000;
dt = 1;   %time steps
T = nPeriods*dt;
t = 0:1:T;
rng('default')
k=randi([1,10],1,nPeriods);
f = (lambda.^k).*exp(-lambda)./factorial(k); % Poission Dist. 
Nd = cumsum(f);
N = [ 0 Nd(1:end) ]; % N(0)=0.
stairs(t,N)   am I correct ?

Comment: I don't know Matlab code, so cannot comment.  It looks roughly right